# How to get Content-Disposition to handle quoted filenames?

Tags: c#, http, http-headers, content-disposition

I am trying to define the filename for Android downloads where the surrounding quotes are required. It seems the ContentDisposition.ToString() doesn't properly handle the escaped characters.

```
string path = "User.pdf";   
var cd_escaped = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition()
{
    FileName = $"\"{path}\""
};
var cd_normal = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition()
{
    FileName = path
};

// Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="\"User.pdf\""
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd_escaped.ToString());
// Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=User.pdf
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd_normal.ToString());
```

I have more complex ContentDisposition objects that I would like to not have to build manually, but still be able to surround with quotes. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you want to use `cd.FileName.ToString()`, and not just `ToString()` the object.

Comment: I was hoping not to manually output the object given how the object ToString handles concatenating all it's relevant properties. Any way to manage that case?

Comment: What exactly is the value you want to send? Just the FileName, or something more?

Comment: What do you mean by, *"It seems the ContentDisposition.ToString() doesn't properly handle the escaped characters."*? What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Strings such as `User.pdf` are handled fine and output filename=User.pdf. But strings like in the answer `$"\"{path}\""` output the string with added escape characters - `filename="\"User"\.pdf"`

Comment: Clarified examples in the question.